# android coding force close

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

here is the code that is giving the force close error running on avd

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button magic;
TextView display;
int random;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    magic=(Button)findViewById(R.id.magic);
    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    magic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);

            display.setText("your number is"+random);

        }
    });

    }
}
```

here is the code i am using even if random function or settext is not used application force closes please help

activity_main.xml not giving any error or warning..........

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/magic8ball"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="171dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/magic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="@string/Magic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Magic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="74dp"
       android:text="@string/Ask"
android:textAppearance="?     android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#EE5533" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the xml file is given where the single waring is related to the textview1 when hard coded

since the text is about to change whether it is good to set it on string.xml or hard code it ?????

Comment: Use logcat to understand what is wrong

Comment: please post some log/stack trace...

Comment: Your LinearLayout is unused. Try your code after removing LinearLayout.

Comment: thanks all guys for replying but when i remove the unnecessary code pointed by rajesh the problem is solved**<android.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp" />**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose you are using following code.

```
**<android.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="144dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp" />**
```

This seems not available.. its working fine in the ICS devices.. but not working in Gingerbread devices.. I think that's the unusable code...